# couldn't match expected type (Int -> Int -> Int) with actual type `(t0, t1, t2)'

Tags: haskell, types, tuples

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to do some tutorials on Haskell before entering uni for computer science.

I got stuck in this program. It takes three numbers and puts them in ascending order. Can anyone help me and tell me whats wrong because it's driving me crazy? Thanks for your time.

```
import Prelude hiding (min,max)
orderTriple :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int -> Int)
max :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
min :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
middle :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int


max x y z
 |(x>=y) && (x>=z)  = x
 |(y>=x) && (y>=z)  = y
 |otherwise     = z

min d e f
 |(d<=e) && (d<=f)  = d
 |(e<=d) && (e<=f)  = e
 |otherwise     = f

middle g h i
 | (g <= (max g h i)) && (g >= (min g h i)) = g
 | (h <= (max g h i)) && (h >= (min g h i)) = h
 | otherwise                    = i

orderTriple (a,b,c) = ((min a b c),(middle a b c),(max a b c))
```

The error is:

```
orderList.hs:23:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Int -> Int -> Int]'
                with actual type `(t0, t1, t2)'
    In the pattern: (a, b, c)
In an equation for `orderTriple':
    orderTriple (a, b, c) = [(min a b c), (middle a b c), (max a b c)]
```

Comment: Are you actually going to be doing Haskell (or some sort of FP) in university? I wish I had gotten that in my program!

Answer (score 6):

You give the compiler wrong type information:

```
orderTriple :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int -> Int)
```

should be

```
orderTriple :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
```

The first typing claims that `orderTriple` converts a function (from two Ints to one) into another such function, which is not at all what your code does.

(Also: +1 for studying FP *in preparation* for a CS program).

Comment: thx a lot about your help but this time it comes up with another error
    <interactive>:1:1:
        The function `orderTriple' is applied to three arguments,
        but its type `(Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)' has only one
        In the expression: orderTriple 3 1 9
        In an equation for `it': it = orderTriple 3 1 9

Comment: The definition of `orderTriple` expects a tuple, that is, comma-separated arguments in parentheses. You must call it that way -- `orderTriples(3,1,9)` -- not with three space-separated (curried) arguments without parentheses.

Comment: @noobie: You may also want to check that you're using round brackets `()` instead of square ones `[]` in the definition of `orderTriple`. The error message you give is different from the code listing above it...

Comment: yeah yeah you are right again! i called the function without the brackets : orderTriple 3 1 9 and thats why it came up with this error! i appreciate your help :) have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

An arrow `->` separates a function's arguments. (Actually it is a little bit more sophisticated) But to separate the arguments of a tuple, use a comma:

```
orderTriple :: (Int,Int,Int) -> (Int,Int,Int)
```

In case of other types, a space is sufficient:

```
Either String Int
```